# make persistent per user mounts to network share on 16.04

Tags: permissions, mount, mountpoint

We have several ubuntu task servers witch write results to windows network shares.
For now the shares are mounted using the fstab and a service account with read/write rights on the share.
The issue is that all users on the task server have read/write rights in all the users subfolders.

What we want to achieve is that we can give the users read/write to there own folder but with no access to there colleagues folders on the share. We need the results to be on the windows share because it must be accessible from windows devices.

Is it possible to make these persistent per-user mounts without having to add every user in a passwd file with username and passwd? The servers are domain joined using pbis / likewise